# How execute a function contained inside a route on form submit?

Tags: python, forms, flask, routes

I have a form. When I submit my form, I want to execute some functions in the route that processes the form data.

Form

```
<form action="{{ url_for('background_process') }}" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />

        <input type="url" id="url" name="url"/>

        <input type ="text" id="mdp-demo" name= "mdp-demo"/>

       <input type=text size=5 name=proglang>
            <a href=# id=process_input><button class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button></a>
    </form>
```

Javascript to post form data to route that processes data.

```
           $(function() {
            $('a#process_input').bind('click', function() {
            $.getJSON('/background_process', {
              proglang: $('input[name="proglang"]').val(),
              url: $('input[name="url"]').val(),
              title: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
              dates: $('input[name="mdp-demo"]').val(),
            }, function(data) {
              $("#result").text(data.result);
            });
            return false;
          });
```

Route that processes the form data.

```
@app.route('/background_process', methods=['GET','POST'])
def background_process():
try:
    create_table()
    data_entry()
    url = request.args.get('url', 0, type=str)
    title = request.args.get('title', 0, type=str)
    dates = request.args.get('dates', 0, type=str)

    if url.lower() == 'https://www.reddit.com/':
        return jsonify(result='You are wise')
    else:
        return jsonify(result='Try again.')
except Exception as e:
    return str(e)
```

I want to execute the create_table() and data_entry() functions when the submit button on the form is clicked.

The result at the moment is that nothing happens. These functions work when executed on app run time outside of a route. It's when they are within a route they don't work. Any suggestions as to what I should do to achieve execution of these functions inside my route?

Comment: im not sure i understand what you are trying to do. when you click submit your flask route get called but it doesnt do what you want it to do?

Comment: @Nullman When I click submit, the url, title and dates get posted to my /background_process route perfectly. The problem is that the create_table()
   and data_entry() functions don't execute. I.e no table is created in my database and thus no data is entered to my db.

Comment: are you getting an exception? if not, then they do run they just dont do what you want them to do. we cant help you fix that if we dont know what they do

Comment: data_entry() doesn't take any argument?